# PDF issue with fonts in adobe, after using overlays in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

We use pdfbox for in one of our applications.
Some pdfs that are overlaid result in "broken" output and fonts.

Below is the sample code I'm using to overlay pdfs.
The pdfs sometimes have different numbers of pages.
We flatten acroforms and set annotations to read-only.
Pdf page rotation and bbox sizing sometimes set differently (especially from scanners) so we try to correct for this.

```
    PDDocument baseDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("base.pdf"));
    PDDocument overlayDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("overlay.pdf"));
    Iterator<PDPage> baseDocumentIterator = baseDocument.getPages().iterator();
    Iterator<PDPage> overlayIterator = overlayDocument.getPages().iterator();
    PDDocument finalOverlayDoc = new PDDocument();
    while(baseDocumentIterator.hasNext() && overlayIterator.hasNext()) {
        PDPage backing = baseDocumentIterator.next();
        //locking annotations per page
        List<PDAnnotation> annotations = backing.getAnnotations();
        for (PDAnnotation a :annotations) {
            a.setLocked(true);
            a.setReadOnly(true);
        }
        // setting size so there's no weird overflow issues
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();
        rect.setLowerLeftX(0);
        rect.setLowerLeftY(0);
        rect.setUpperRightX(backing.getBBox().getWidth());
        rect.setUpperRightY(backing.getBBox().getHeight());
        backing.setCropBox(rect);
        backing.setMediaBox(rect);
        backing.setBleedBox(rect);
        PDPage pg = overlayIterator.next();
        //setting rotation if different. Some scanners cause issues.
        if(backing.getRotation()!= pg.getRotation())
        {
            pg.setRotation(-backing.getRotation());
        }
        finalOverlayDoc.addPage(pg);
    }
    finalOverlayDoc.close();
    //flatten acroform
    PDAcroForm acroForm = baseDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    if (acroForm != null) {
        acroForm.flatten();
        acroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);
    }
    Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
    overlay.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.FOREGROUND);
    overlay.setInputPDF(baseDocument);
    overlay.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(finalOverlayDoc);

    Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    overlay.overlay(ovmap);
    PDPageTree allOverlayPages = overlayDocument.getPages();
    if(baseDocument.getPages().getCount() < overlayDocument.getPages().getCount()) //Additional pages in the overlay pdf need to be appended to the base pdf.
    {
        for(int i=baseDocument.getPages().getCount();i<allOverlayPages.getCount(); i++)
        {
            baseDocument.addPage(allOverlayPages.get(i));
        }
    }
    PDDocument finalDocument = new PDDocument();
    for(PDPage p: baseDocument.getPages()){
        finalDocument.addPage(p);
    }

    String filename = "examples/merge_pdf_examples/debug.pdf";
    filename = filename + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf";
    finalDocument.save(filename);
    finalDocument.close();
    baseDocument.close();
    overlayDocument.close();
```

Comment: Please explain exactly which errors you want to be able to repair.

Comment: @mkl, thanks. I see now that Preflight returns loads of different issues with pdfs. I've added the detail from 3 problematic pdfs. We're using overlay() from pdfbox, to overlay our pdf on top of problematic pdf. The majority of the time this works perfectly, there's just a few occasions where we get the above mentioned problem. Is using prepress from pdfbox, before overlaying, an option to resolve these issues?

Comment: The errors you show appear to be PDF/A related, not PDF related in general. Is that really what you mean? Your question originally sounded like you meant general PDF errors.

Comment: @mkl, thanks .I didn't realize those differences until you mentioned it. So it sounds like like I'm using preflight wrong or shouldn't be using preflight at all. The issue is that I don't know what's wrong with the original pdf, just that these "erroneous" pdfs, when merged with overlay, fail to open in adobe and the text turns to gibberish.

Comment: According to your PreflightParser link: *The Apache Preflight library is a Java tool that implements a parser compliant with the ISO-19005 specification (aka PDF/A-1).* So I'm afraid it's not for generic PDF validation, only for specific PDF/A-1 validation.

Comment: If those *"erroneous" pdfs* fail the same way, can you share one of them for analysis?

Comment: @mkl https://drive.google.com/file/d/10lYNfkQlUvxeZ2rFps2ozBO-zgGrnVeU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So it's really a different problem, i.e. overlying not working properly. Make sure you are using the latest version. Share the second file and the code for the overlay (better create a new question).

Comment: Adobe Preflight in profile "Report PDF syntax issues" reports the viewer preference **PrintScaling** as a problem, probably because it is defined since PDF 1.6 but the PDF claims compliance to PDF 1.4. Furthermore, it reports an empty **AcroForm** dictionary; this indeed is an error, if you have an **AcroForm** dictionary, it must contain the required **AcroForm** keys, in particular **Fields**.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr One special property of the file is that the page resources, in particular the font resources, are inherited from the pages node above. Does Overlay probably have issues with inherited resources?

Comment: I ran a quick test with Overlay and your file, and I could not reproduce overlaying issues. Can you share a short example (code plus files) that illustrates the issue? And please indicate the PDFBox version you are using and also run your example with the current PDFBox release..

Comment: @mkl I had a quick look, I don't think so.

Comment: @RobCurtis So you shared the code but not the PDFs. You didn't mention what version you have. Your code is very long, is there smaller code that reproduces the problem? Alternatively, can you reproduce the problem from the command line application? https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#overlaypdf

Comment: Considering what I said above - that the page resources are inherited - I think your loop generating the `finalOverlayDoc` from the `overlayDocument` is the actual problem as it transfers page objects and so loses everything inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in the PDF file you shared relevant for using `Overlay`.

It uses one PDF feature which is seldom used, though, the pages *inherit* resources from their parent node: Page objects in a PDF are arranged in a tree with the actual pages being leaves; a page object in this tree often itself carries all the information defining it but a number of page properties can also be carried by an inner node and inherited by descendant pages unless they override them.

After you shared your code it turns out that you have a preparation step which loses all inherited information: When you generate `finalOverlayDoc` from `overlayDocument` you essentially do:

```java
while(overlayIterator.hasNext()) {
    PDPage pg = overlayIterator.next();
    //setting rotation if different. Some scanners cause issues.
    finalOverlayDoc.addPage(pg);
}
```

*([OverlayDocuments](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/merge/OverlayDocuments.java#L116) test `testOverlayPreparationExampleBroken`)*

Here you only transport the page object itself, losing all inherited properties.

For the document at hand you can fix this by explicitly setting the page resources to the inherited ones:

```java
while(overlayIterator.hasNext()) {
    PDPage pg = overlayIterator.next();
    pg.setResources(pg.getResources());
    //setting rotation if different. Some scanners cause issues.
    finalOverlayDoc.addPage(pg);
}
```

*([OverlayDocuments](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/merge/OverlayDocuments.java#L149) test `testOverlayPreparationFixedExampleBroken`)*

Beware, though: This only explicitly sets the page *resources* but there also are other page attributes which can be inherited.

I would propose, therefore, that you don't create a new `PDDocument` at all; instead of moving the `overlayDocument` pages to `finalOverlayDoc` only change them in place. If `overlayDocument` has more pages than `baseDocument`, you additionally have to remove excess pages from `overlayDocument`. Then use `overlayDocument` in overlaying instead of `finalOverlayDoc`.

---

Looking further down your code I see you repeat the anti-pattern of moving page objects to other documents without respecting inherited properties again and again. I guess you should completely overhaul that code, removing that anti-pattern.